# If statements with copied formula in the outputs

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am using a standard format if statement, in this case `+if(A15="Sub Total", W15, (W15+AA15))` in cell AC15. W15 contains the formula **sum(W10:W15).**

The if statement results in a value in **AC15** of **sum(W10:W15)** rather than the relative formula **sum(AC10:AC15)**.  This is important as the figures in column AC vary in subsequent iterations independently of those in column AC.

Sounds like a simple problem - but I cannot resolve.

Answer (score 1):

If you reference a cell in a formula, that cell's value will be used in the formula, not its underlying formula (if any).

> > W15 contains the formula sum(W10:W15)

That is a circular reference. W15 cannot include its own value in the sum. Also, if you want in AC15 a formula `sum(AC10:AC15)` this would also be a circular reference.

Straighten out your data layout.